# Why were the Miami Dolphins chosen to be portrayed?

Tags: ace-ventura-pet-detective

In the 1994 movie [*Ace Ventura: Pet Detective*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0109040/), the mascot is stolen from the NFL team, the Miami Dolphins.  The Miami Dolphins are an actual NFL American Football team.

There are several cameos by actual Miami Dolphins players and coaches in the movie.  The movie portrays the out-of-universe Miami Dolphins organization fairly accurately (apart from a missed field goal that lost the superbowl for them).

It is widely speculated that the character of Ray Finkle is based on [Scott Norwood](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scott_Norwood) who missed the game winning field goal in Superbowl XXV. However;   Norwood played for the Buffalo Bills, not the Miami Dolphins.

The [Miami Dolphins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami_Dolphins) (up to the movie's release in 1994) have never been in a position in a superbowl where a field goal would have won the game for them.  There have been other NFL teams up to that point with closer scoring superbowl scores and bumbled plays that lost superbowls other than the Dolphins.

**Did filmmakers chose the Miami Dolphins before they started writing the script and made adjustments to adhere to the Miami Dolphins and their organization?**  There are several other professional sports teams which have an animal as their mascot which could have been used.  **Was there a specific reason for using the Miami Dolphins?**

Comment: Sub-question: *were early drafts of the script based on the Buffalo Bills rather than the Miami Dolphins?*

Comment: The real final score of Super Bowl XIX (1985) was San Francisco 38, Miami 16. The game footage of 'Ray Finkle' used in the film is actually a 1984 clip of Dolphins kicker Uwe von Schamann.

Comment: 1) Do the Miami Dolphins actually have a live dolphin as a mascot? 2) Do any other NFL teams have live animals as mascots? If #1 is yes and #2 is no, then maybe they were used due to need for a live animal theft...

Comment: @miltonaut 1)  No.  The Dolphins had a mascot named Flipper in the late 60's, but didn't use him anymore due to costs.  They have a mascot named "TD" which is a human in a dolphin costume. 2) Yes.  The Denver Broncos have a horse, the Seattle Seahawks have a hawk, the Buffalo Bills have an actual Buffalo, the Baltimore Ravens have 2 actual Ravens, the Tennessee Titans have an actual raccoon.  The Ravens and Titans weren't even teams when the movie was made.  In 1994, there were actually more teams with actual animal mascots.

Comment: It was because they needed a Dolphin to be stolen (or some other large aquatic animal).

Comment: @BlueMoon93 How do you know this?  Why did they have to have an aquatic animal?

Answer (score 3):

I can't find any backup, but I read somewhere way-back-when that they needed a mascot who could (possibly) kick a field goal, to ridicule the actual kicker who missed his attempt.  The dolphin is the only mascot capable of doing something like that.

Comment: You have obviously never seen _Gus_ ;)

Comment: I feel like other animals could kick a field goal given proper training. Esp. since the FG distance wasnt very far for Snowflake

Comment: According to steelersquirrel's comment, other options include a horse, hawk, buffalo, raven and raccoon.  Exactly which one of those are you counting on to kick a field goal?

Comment: I bet someone could train a horse to kick a football up-ish. Then they could just do a cut scene with the ball going in. I do agree with your greater point though that a dolphin would probably be easier to train than a cheese wedge or a steel beam.